# Cordova file plugin not working to delete a file

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have been working on an app with AngularJS, Cordova, and Ionic. In the past, I have been storing some information on a file on the device using the Cordova file plugin.

I want to move away from taking this approach and delete the file.

Here is my code snippet:

```
function migrateAwayFromDataFile() {

    console.log(' migrate away from data file ');

    console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory); //file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/

    window.requestFileSystem(cordova.file.dataDirectory, 0, function (fs) {
        fs.root.getFile('filename.json', { create: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.remove(function () {
                console.log(' config file deleted ');
                ErrorMessageAndDebugLogService.logDebug('Config file has been deleted successfully.');
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                ErrorMessageAndDebugLogService.logDebugError('Could not delete Config file. ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
 migrate away from data file 
bundle.min.js:1 file:///data/data/com.myapp.app/files/
cordova.js:420 Wrong type for parameter "type" of requestFileSystem: Expected Number, but got String.
checkArgs @ cordova.js:420
cordova.js:422 Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "type" of requestFileSystem: Expected Number, but got String.
    at Object.checkArgs (cordova.js:422)
    at requestFileSystem (plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js:50)
    at bundle.min.js:1
    at Object.l [as initializeApp] (bundle.min.js:1)
    at bundle.min.js:1
    at Array.<anonymous> (vendors.min.js:1)
    at Channel.o (vendors.min.js:1)
    at Channel.fire (cordova.js:840)
    at cordova.js:226
```

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

First param of requestFileSystem() must be the type, not the directory :

```
window.requestFileSystem('json'
```